# How to add defer attribute to the bundle generated using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, walmart-electrode

We are bundling our react application using webpack. and it generates a bundle which is injected using script tag

```
<script src="/js/main.bundle.c02b9dc1468b4bf6c7e3.js"></script>
```

This main.bundle size is big, that it affects performance. The suggestion is that to make this js bundle to load defer / async.

```
<script defer src="/js/main.bundle.c02b9dc1468b4bf6c7e3.js"></script>
```

How to add defer attribute to the script tag. Since this script tag is injected dynamically by webpack, i am not able to find it anywhere in my application.

Comment: Are you using `html-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: No im not using it.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?